# Make a TextView visible when AsyncTask starts

Tags: android, asynchronous, textview, task, show

I want my `AsyncTask` class to change the visibility of a `TextView` from my layout and I get a fatal error. If I want to get the text value of the `TextView`, it works fine, but when trying to set the visibility it just crashes.

```
// Main Activity (MainActivity.java)
Context MainContext= getApplicationContext();
new MyAsyncTask((TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view)).execute();

// My Async Task (MyAsyncTask.java)
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String> {
    private Context context;
private TextView my_text_view;

public MyAsyncTask (TextView my_text_view){
        this.context = MainActivity.MainContext;
    this.txt_loading = my_text_view;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    my_text_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // crashes
    Log.i("Value: ", String.valueOf(this.my_text_view.getText())); // O.K.!
    return null;
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }

}
```

How can I make it work? Also, can I get the `TextView` from the Context? I don't want to send it as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: The method `doInBackground` is running in a different thread from the UI, so you cannot update the UI. Use your empty `onPreExecute` method to set the visibility `my_text_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. This method runs on the UI thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It crashes because you are manipuling with `UI` in **background Thread**. This is not allowed and you can't do it.

```
my_text_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**User Interface** may be updated / changed only from original / main / UI `Thread`. AsyncTask provides some methods that actually runs on UI `Thread`.

These methods are exactly designated for reach your goal: *to perform any UI update*.

When you want to update `UI` from `AsyncTask`, you can use:

- **onPreExecute()**
- **onProgressUpdate()**
- **onPostExecute()**

Comment: Thanks! Second question: can I get the TextView from the context? Something like `context.get?????From()`?

Comment: I recommend to you pass TextView object via constructor of AsyncTask class(if you are using it as separate class). If you have your AsyncTask as inner class in your Activity class so you can access with it normally but it can be changed only in meant methods.

Comment: O.K. Thanks. It's because I have more elements that should be changed `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: so you can pass these elements via contructor or in your case rather use AsyncTask as inner class and then you have access to all UI widgets etc.

Comment: I agree with you @sajmon_d. But i want to know the following from ali

Where is Services constructor coming from??
Secondly your `my_text_view` is not even initialized and where is `txt.loading` defined??

Comment: I could make them public in MainActivity, I suppose I could access them from AsyncTask

Comment: ok he corrected the name of the constructor!!, but `my_text_view` is still not initialized!!

Comment: Generally, you should initialize all UI components before using them in AsyncTask or Service etc. :)) just inilialize textView before AsyncTask instance is declared and executed.